# Magento 1.9 OSC Validation Field

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout

Is there a way to validate fields in OSC, in a way that as an specific  country is selected, another fields like 'Postal Code' would only allow the introduction of numbers?

Thanks for your collaborations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding validation class to zipcode field on change of country dropdown. You can do something like this

```
$('#billing:country_id').on('change', function() {
    if(this.value == 'your_country')
    {
        $( "#billing:postcode" ).addClass("validation_class");
    }
    else
    {
       //remove validation class if not particular country
       if($( "#billing:postcode" ).hasClass("validation_class"))
       {
          $( "#billing:postcode" ).removeClass("validation_class");
       }
    }
})
```